# Regression where IV is a Quadrant

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I am running a regression where I regress a dependent variable Vi on two other variables $X_i$ and $Y_i$. Based on these, I create an auxilliary independent variable $Q_i$, where $Q_i$ is a 4-level factor variable that informs us whether the levels of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are high/low respectively (based on some thresholds).

Therefore, the interpretation of the output of this regression will be based on the effect on the dependent variable on which of these four quadrants the observation lies in.

Is there a way for me to obtain the same interpretation but without using the auxilliary factor variable and directly using the variables $X_i$ and $Y_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ and $t$ be the X and Y thresholds

Note that $\text{sign}(X_i-s)$ tells you whether you're right or left of the X-threshold and  $\text{sign}(Y_i-t)$ tells you whether you're above or below the Y-threshold.

So for example,  $(2\,\text{sign}(X_i-s)+\text{sign}(Y_i-t)+5)/2$ takes the values 1,2,3 and 4:

[image: Plot showing values according to the formula using the sign function]

If you need the labelling to progress "around the circle", that can also be done, for example using the atan2 function.

$Q_i= \lfloor 3-\frac{2}{\pi}\text{atan2}(X_i-s,Y_i-t)\rfloor$

This would label the 4th quadrant 1, and so on around from there:

[image: Plot showing values in the quadrants labelled using the above atan2-based function]

Alternatively if you subtract 1 from this it's the usual numbering mod 4 (i.e. you get quadrant I labelled "1", II labelled "2", III labelled "3" and IV labelled "0").

These sorts of functions are (of course!) not linear in X and Y.